# Calling a variable from another funtion

Tags: python, function, variables, qt-designer, calling-convention

**Intro to what my goal is:**
I created a GUI in QT designer with two buttons. One to open a browser to search for a text file with my data. The other to open this data file and find the two columns of data to plot.

**The problem:**
I have been trying to use a variable in one function which was created in another function. Other tutorials mentioned "returning" the variable. Another one suggested setting the text in a label or textbox to the value and pulling it in using ".get()". How can I use the Path of the file i select in the "file_open" function in the "data_analysis" function? I keep getting "undefined name path"

I really hope someone can help, I am a complete beginner! if you need the full code or further details i will edit and post it. Thanks in advance!

```
def file_open(self):
    def main():
        Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
        in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        Path = in_path
        return Path

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

#once a file is selected, pick out required data and plot it   
def data_analysis(self):

    f = open(Path, "r")
    data = []
    y = f.readlines()
    x = list(y)
    x_value = []
    y_value = []

    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        if x[i].find("CORRECTION_FACTOR")>-1:
            for y in range(i+2, (len(x) - 3)):
                data = x[y].split("\t")
                x_value.append(data[3])
                y_value.append(data[5])

    print x_value
    print y_value
    plot(x_value, y_value)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you have a local function and an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block in the middle of what looks like a method of some class you haven't shown us? That… doesn't make any sense at all. But if you want to make that work somehow, you're going to make to `return main()`, not just call it and ignore the results. That will make `file_open` return the path to whoever calls it.

Comment: Also, why are you using a Tkinter file dialog in a Qt app? If that happens to work instead of, say, hanging your whole application, that's just pure luck.

Comment: Finally, if these really are methods of some class that you haven't shown us, the simplest thing to do is to just store the value in an instance attribute: do `self.path = …` in the first function, and you can `open(self.path)` in the other function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments they are a great help. The code was quite long and I hoped to keep it short and to the point so only included (what i thought) was needed. This code lies within the class created by QT designer. I see what you mean about return main(), that should help a lot!

Comment: I didn't know how to open a file dialog in QT at the time, so i stuck with what I know using Tkinter hoping it was an easy fix. But that does solve the problem of why my program hangs and needs a restart, i will remove Tkinter and stick with QTdesigner. THanks!

Comment: The file open dialog in qt: `QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`